# Induced Monoidal Structure by Isomorphism

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ be a pair of categories and assume they are isomorphic via a functor
$$F \colon \mathscr{C} \longrightarrow \mathscr{D}.$$
Suppose that $(\mathscr{D}, \otimes, 1, \sigma)$ has a symmetric monoidal structure (not necessarily strict), where $1$ is the unit and $\sigma$ is the braiding. Then, it seems natural to think that such structure can be transported to $\mathscr{C}$, defining
$$x\Box y := F^{-1}(F(x)\otimes F(y))$$
for every $x,y \in \operatorname{obj}(\mathscr{C})$,
$$f\Box g:= F^{-1}(F(f)\otimes F(g))$$
for every $f,g \in \operatorname{Hom}(\mathscr{C})$ and similarly for the rest of the monoidal structure. However, I'm not sure about if this really yields a monoidal structure on $\mathscr{C}$. Is this result (or similar) proven in some reference or something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is easy to prove if $F$ is an *isomorphism* ($F$ just preserves every monoidal category axiom precisely; this is "transport of structure"). An isomorphism will even send strict monoidal structures to strict monoidal structures. The interesting statement is that this remains true if you only require that $F$ be an *equivalence*; then $F$ will no longer preserve strict monoidal structures and this is what you need non-strict monoidal structures for.

Comment: Is there any proof of the equivalence case in the mathematical literature?

Comment: Probably? Here's an MO thread about it: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168351/inducing-a-monoidal-structure-using-an-equivalence-of-categories

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583042/can-functor-carry-over-a-monoidal-structure